# MySQL, Get users rank

Tags: sql, mysql, rank

I have a mysql table like below:

```
id     name     points
1      john     4635
3      tom      7364
4      bob      234
6      harry    9857
```

I basically want to get an individual user rank without selecting all of the users.  I only want to select a single user by id and get the users rank which is determined by the number of points they have.

For example, get back tom with the rank 2 selecting by the id 3.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT  uo.*, 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    users ui
        WHERE   (ui.points, ui.id) >= (uo.points, uo.id)
        ) AS rank
FROM    users uo
WHERE   id = @id
```

Dense rank:

```
SELECT  uo.*, 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ui.points)
        FROM    users ui
        WHERE   ui.points >= uo.points
        ) AS rank
FROM    users uo
WHERE   id = @id
```

Comment: I love it. A bit of tuning and it fits my needs. Tnx for sharing!

Comment: Minor issue: If there are ties, this will return the highest rank rather than the lowest. If you want the lowest, change the condition to `>` and the value to `COUNT(*)+1`.

Comment: @Barmar: if there are ties, this will use `id` as a secondary criterion.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize you could do a compound comparison like that. Although it seems arbitrary that a player should be ranked better just because they have a higher ID. Everyone in a tie should get the same rank.

Comment: @Barmar: to emulate `DENSE_RANK` (that's what you are talknig about) just replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT points)`

Comment: That will merge ties ahead of you, too. If the scores are 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, the ranks should be 1, 2, 2, 4, 4 (or, more specifically, 1, 2-3, 2-3, 4-5, 4-5).

Comment: @Barmar: there are three window functions for ranking: `ROW_NUMBER` (my original query), `RANK` (your previous comment) and `DENSE_RANK` (my previous comment). Since they all exist and are used I wouldn't use "should" without knowing the OP's exact intentions.

Comment: I think the way rankings in a game are usually reported is the way I described. They'll report something like "tied for 4th and 5th place". If there's a tie for 1st place, the player after them gets 3rd place, not 2nd.

Comment: @Quassnoi You seem to understand this much better than most users, fantastic work!

Answer (score 2):

Solution by @Quassnoi will fail in case of ties. Here is the solution that will work in case of ties:

```
SELECT *,
IF (@score=ui.points, @rank:=@rank, @rank:=@rank+1) rank,
@score:=ui.points score
FROM users ui,
(SELECT @score:=0, @rank:=0) r
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: To note, the rank will be 0 if first place has a score of 0. Additionally, in the event of ties, the rank is incremented, not skipped e.g. 10 - 1st, 9 - 2nd, 9 - 2nd, 6 - 3rd. Additionally, the fetching of rows should be in a subquery, as the order is applied after the rankings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET @rownum := 0;
 SELECT rank, score FROM ( SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `score` ,`user_id`
 FROM leaderboard 
 ORDER BY  `score` DESC , `updated_timestamp` ) as result WHERE `user_id`=$user_id
 LIMIT 1
```