# Find 3rd Greatest Value with MySQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with 3 columns:

`Name` `department` `salary`

How can I determine using one query to find 3rd highest `salary` in each `department`?

Comment: Yeah...what have you tried thus far?

Comment: why -ve to this i hv no clue 

SELECT MAX(SALARY) , DEPARTMENT FROM TABLE GROYP BY DEPARTMENT

Comment: This is actually a good question. Unfortunately it is titled, formatted, and phrased so incorrectly that it will probably be ignored

Comment: @mattedgod: Perhaps you can improve it?

Comment: i know its a good question , please remove -ve

Comment: @eggyal Valid point, I worked on the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to `LIMIT` a correlated subquery, but it's not especially efficient:

```
SELECT   department, (
  SELECT   salary
  FROM     my_table t2
  WHERE    t2.department = t1.department
  ORDER BY salary DESC
  LIMIT    2, 1
)
FROM     my_table t1
GROUP BY department
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to eggyal's excellent answer, here's a query that will give you the names, too, of those that have salary equal to the third (in each department):

```
SELECT 
    t.name, t.department, t.salary AS third_salary
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT department 
      FROM tableX
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    tableX AS t
      ON  t.department = d.department 
      AND t.salary = 
      ( SELECT tt.salary                         -- notice that this
        FROM tableX AS tt                        -- subquery is
        WHERE tt.department = d.department       -- exactly the same as
        ORDER BY tt.salary DESC                  -- the one in 
          LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2                       -- @eggyal's answer
      ) ;
```

Comment: Nice. +1 The questioner could also use the Department table in place of subquery d if he has one, to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This RANK question is similar to this one:
[MySQL, Get users rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293817/mysql-get-users-rank)

I you can thy this:

```
SELECT  s.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    salaries si
        WHERE   si.salary >= s.salary AND si.department = s.department
        ) AS rank
FROM    salaries s
WHERE s.rank = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, department, salary
FROM (SELECT name, department, salary, IF(@dept=(@dept:=department), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx 
      FROM employee e, (SELECT @dept:=0, @auto:=1) A
      ORDER BY department, salary DESC ) AS A 
WHERE indx = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Simple and elegant solution :

```
-- get second and third highest employee based on salary from all departments
WITH rankedemployee AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentid ORDER BY salary DESC) AS denserank
    FROM employee
)
SELECT * FROM rankedemployee WHERE denserank IN (2,3);
```

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/