# MYSQL SELECT rank of user (more than x & less than y)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm a bit stuck with a php/Mysql Query. I got 2 tables :

```
  table_users              table_ranks
----------------    ------------------------
| id  | points |    | name | points_needed |
----------------    ------------------------
| 1   |   2    |    | lvl0 |      0        |
| 2   |   10   |    | lvl1 |      10       |
| 3   |   21   |    | lvl2 |      20       |
| 4   |   29   |    | lvl3 |      30       |
----------------    ------------------------
```

I need an ouput like this :

- User_1 = lvl0 (because user has 2 points)
- User_2 = lvl1 (because user has just reached 10 points)
- ...
- User_4 = lvl2 (because user has not yet reached 30 points)

Think you :)

Regards.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Show your efforts ? Query you have tried ?

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293817/mysql-get-users-rank but i'm a bit lost at the "AS" thing. And it's not exactly the same kind of ranking BTW :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT
  tu.id,
  tr.name,
  tu.points
FROM table_ranks as tr
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_ranks LIMIT 1,69596585953484) as l
    ON l.points_needed = (SELECT MIN(points_needed) FROM table_ranks WHERE points_needed > tr.points_needed limit 1)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_users AS tu ON tu.points >= tr.points_needed AND tu.points < l.points_needed
WHERE tu.id IS NOT NULL
group by tu.id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/832ccb/2)

Output

```
-------------------------
| id  | points   | name |
-------------------------
| 1   |   lvl0   | 2    |
| 2   |   lvl1   | 10   |
| 3   |   lvl2   | 21   |
| 4   |   lvl2   | 29   |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Awesome! Do the job, and is flexible. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

give this a try, a little bit messy due to table design,

```
SELECT  u.*, r.name
FROM    table_users u
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT x.name, 
                   x.points_needed start_point, 
                   COALESCE(y.points_needed - 1, 2000000) end_point
            FROM
            (
              SELECT name, points_needed, @rank:=@rank+1 ranks
              FROM table_ranks a, (SELECT @rank:=0) b
              ORDER BY points_needed
            ) x
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
              SELECT name, points_needed, @rank1:=@rank1+1 ranks
              FROM table_ranks a, (SELECT @rank1:=0) b
              ORDER BY points_needed
            ) y ON x.ranks+1 = y.ranks
        ) r ON u.points BETWEEN r.start_point AND r.end_point
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9263/13)

Comment: It seems to work, but a bit complex compared to the answer by @raheel-shan. Think you BTW